# Error 403 generating credentials through Hashicorp Vault

Tags: mysql, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to setup database secrets through Hashicorp vault for MySQL Database. I've followed the instructions provided in the documents (https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/index.html) for the configuration of database and role.

However when I try to generate the credential I am facing an error - 403 Permission Denied.

The logs on the server do not show any errors as well.

I am running the server on the Dev mode as I am trying to implement a prototype.

Is there some specific permissions that I need to setup and have missed?

Appreciate any help or feedback.

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem was due to a mismatch on the config of the database and the roles.

The role I was trying to get the credential for was not in the allowed roles for the database.

Thanks,
Aravind